# Writing to stderr using write() from thread

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, stderr

In a Qt/C++ application I need to use write() to print some text to `stderr`. I'm doing something like this multiple times:

```
  write(stdErrDescriptor, "H", 1);
  write(stdErrDescriptor, "e", 1);
  write(stdErrDescriptor, "l", 1);
  write(stdErrDescriptor, "l", 1);
  write(stdErrDescriptor, "o", 1);
  write(stdErrDescriptor, "\n", 1);
```

I'm calling that from the main thread and a sub thread. The output of the threads should be serialized by internal program logic. This means the main thread should not print at the same time as the sub thread. This seems to be true since in reality I could never see interleaved lines on the console. Still there is something going on that I do not understand.

I expected to see something like this:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

However I get this:

```
Hello
Hello
H
e
l
l
o

H
e
l
l
o

Hello
Hello
```

Please note that lines are not interleaved. Still a line feed is added after each write() call when executing the code snippet from a sub thread.

The effect is completely reproducible when starting the debug build from Qt Creator under gdb supervision.
However when manually stepping through the code or when running the debug build without debugger the output looks just fine.

I'm running the code on Kubuntu 20.04 and GCC 12.

What is going on?

Comment: looks for me as if the development suite itself is adding a newline each time the stdout's source is changing to something unequal from main thread ... probably to increase readability. Doing multiple write(x,y,**1**)'s for longer strings anyway is not very efficient and you should think about collecting the output in a buffer (string or else) and output the final thing in ONE call to write().

Comment: Maybe you are right. That would be nasty. I will think about that. Problem is that I'm currently using the same code in standard signal handlers that have very strong restrictions on what API calls are allowed. But I guess I could split the code paths to solve the issue.

Comment: Run a `gdb` session to see what is going on.

Comment: @Zazaeil This didn't help. Please read my entire post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-29100

The problem can also be reproduced with no threads involved.